# Nginx throws a 404 error code when targeting a specific subdomain

Tags: nginx, subdomain, config, reverse-proxy

I'm having a hard time configuring nginx as a reverse proxy.
Let's see what I want to achieve:[image]

The idea is to have Nginx handling all web request to the internal network and redirect to the good one according to the subdomain.

In order to achieve it, I have created one configuration file for each domain. The first one redirecting to App1 is working properly. I have a hard time with the second one.

Here is my subdomain2.company.com.conf

```
    log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name $host to: $upstream_addr: $request $status upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';
underscores_in_headers on;
upstream connecteddevice {
        server 192.168.1.21:8021;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.connecteddevice.company.com connecteddevice.company.com;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.connecteddevice.company.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://connecteddevice.company.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name connecteddevice.company.com;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/connecteddevice.company.com.error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/connecteddevice.company.com.access.log upstreamlog;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/connecteddevice.company.com/chain.pem;
        include snippets/ssl.conf;
        include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://connecteddevice/;
    }

    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

The thing is that with this configuration, requesting js file at the root of the domain returns a 404.
when I call directly http://192.168.1.21:8021/webportal.js everything is ok
but calling https://subdomain2.company.com/webportal.js returns a 404 and the body of the response contains the index.html. The same happens with css requests.

What's wrong with what I did ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The only difference that I can see is that the Host header will be different in the two requests. One receives a Host header set to `192.168.1.21:8021`. Could the connected device be sensitive to the value of the Host header?

Comment: It could be, at least, it's worth a try

Comment: You could make your tests using `curl` which allows you to set the Host header using a command line option.

Comment: The thing is that with curl with one header accept-compression I got a 200